# AWS SES send mail openssl authentication failure

Tags: email, openssl, smtp

I'm trying to send mail from an ubuntu client through the SES service from AWS. I'm following [this tutorial](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/send-email-smtp-client-command-line.html). I've gotten all the way to the part where I actually send the mail. I have double and triple checked that I am using the SES generated credentials, NOT IAM. I have double and triple checked that I am using the base64 encoded strings of those credentials, created according to the tutorial instructions. I am not using a configuration set and have removed the line from my copy of the test email file.

Here is the output I am seeing:

```
depth=2 C = US, O = Amazon, CN = Amazon Root CA 1
verify return:1
depth=1 C = US, O = Amazon, OU = Server CA 1B, CN = Amazon
verify return:1
depth=0 CN = email-smtp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com
verify return:1
220 email-smtp.amazonaws.com ESMTP SimpleEmailService-d-EUWQVEJ8B EQFr3e36SskrySJu5nG9
250-email-smtp.amazonaws.com
250-8BITMIME
250-AUTH PLAIN LOGIN
250 Ok
334 VXNlcm5hbWU6
334 UGFzc3dvcmQ6
535 Authentication Credentials Invalid
530 Authentication required
503 Error: need MAIL command
503 Error: need MAIL command
500 Error: command not implemented
500 Error: command not implemented
500 Error: command not implemented
500 Error: bad syntax
500 Error: command not implemented
500 Error: bad syntax
221 Bye
```

Amazon's note on error codes only tells me what 530 and 535 are. For 535 it says "The application that you use to send email didn't provide the correct SMTP credentials to Amazon SES. Note that your SMTP credentials aren't the same as your AWS credentials. For more information, see Obtaining your Amazon SES SMTP credentials." In case you didn't know what it means for credentials to be invalid. 530 happens, I assume, because the credentials were invalid.

Can anyone tell me what the 334 codes are? I suspect the answer may lie here:

```
334 VXNlcm5hbWU6
334 UGFzc3dvcmQ6
```

I thought at first these might be the beginning of my Base64 encoded strings, but they don't match. And I have tried this with various smtp users with different usernames and passwords and these two strings are always the same.

Otherwise, if anyone knows what could be causing this authentication failure, assistance is greatly appreciated.

Comment: `Authentication Credentials Invalid` <-- pretty self-explanatory that whatever credentials you're using are wrong/bad here.

Comment: Yeah, it's not, though. The problem was with the region, not the credentials.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a problem with using my macbook to encode the user + password via base64. Always being stuck on the same line as you are. I then used an amazon linux vm to encode them, which worked.

Besides that:

- check if the user has the correct IAM rights
- check that you are using the right region in the request

Comment: For clarity if anyone else is stuck on this, my problem was that I was generating the users in the wrong region by mistake.